# C++ Smart Pointers and pointer-to-pointer output API's. Templated "wrapper"

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

In many API's especially C and COM-like API's, factory functions will create objects and store them in a caller provided location using a pointer to pointer. This is not directly compatible with std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr, and others following the same style (e.g. for COM or other intrusive reference counting schemes).

```
void myApiFactory(int x, Foo **out);

std::unique_ptr<Foo> myFoo;
myApiFactory(33, &myFoo);//not possible

//works, but bit of a pain, especially with API's that have lots of such things
Foo *tmp = nullptr;
myApiFactory(33, &tmp);
myFoo.reset(tmp);

//What I'm looking for
myApiFactory(33, outPtr(myFoo));
```

Implementation I am thinking of, which does seem to compile, but I am not sure it is correct and safe (e.g like I understand `(Foo**)(&myUniquePtr)` is not safe but compiles and works for me)?

```
/**@brief Type created and returned by outPtr(T &smartPtr)*/
template<class T>
class OutPtr
{
public:
    typedef typename T::pointer pointer;
    /**Constructor for outPtr*/
    explicit OutPtr(T &smartPtr)
        : smartPtr(&smartPtr)
        , ptr(NULL)
    {}
    /**Move constructor for outPtr return*/
    OutPtr(OutPtr<T> &&mv)
        : smartPtr(mv.smartPtr)
        , ptr(mv.ptr)
    {
        mv.smartPtr = NULL;
        mv.ptr = NULL;
    }

    /**Destructor that stores the pointer set to the pointer to pointer in the
     * provided smart pointer.
     */
    ~OutPtr()
    {
        if (smartPtr)
            smartPtr->reset(ptr);
    }

    /**Implicit conversion to give the pointer to pointer to the function being
     * called.
     */
    operator pointer* ()
    {
        assert(ptr == NULL);
        return &ptr;
    }
private:
    T* smartPtr;
    pointer ptr;
    //Should not be used, cause a compile error
    OutPtr(const OutPtr&);
    OutPtr& operator = (const OutPtr&);
    OutPtr& operator = (OutPtr&&);
};


/**Provides a safe means to store an output pointer directly into an
 * std::unique_ptr or similar smart pointer. The only requirement
 * is that there is a pointer typedef, and a reset method that accepts a
 * pointer of that type.
 *
 * void someFunction(int a, int b, Foo **out);
 * 
 * std::unique_ptr<Foo,MyDeleter> foo;
 * someFunction(4, 23, outPtr(foo));
 */
template<class T>
OutPtr<T> outPtr(T &ptr)
{
    return OutPtr<T>(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This should probably be on Code Review.

Comment: It looks like example code (`std::unique_ptr<Foo> myFoo;`, etc.), if you post your real, working code, it would be on topic for Code Review.

Comment: `(Foo**)(&myUniquePtr)` definitely smells. Badly.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Foo> myFoo{[]{ Foo* p; myApiFactory(33, &p); return p; }()};` works, but is fairly hideous.

Answer (score -1):

This can work:

```
auto p = myFoo.get();
myApiFactory(33, &p);
```

Because the address stored in `myFoo` is stored in `p` as a l-value.

Comment: doesn't this need a reference ?